# Which one is grammatically correct in the context?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

According to Einstein, a lot of energy is needed as a spacecraft nears the speed of light.
Therefore,

> 1. If Einstein is correct, it will be impossible for humans to travel at the speed of light.
> 2. If Einstein is correct, it would be impossible for humans to travel at the speed of light.
>
> What are the differences among the above sentences if both are correct?
>   Because I wonder if it is possible to use "would" in the main clause while the conditional clause is a present tense?

Comment: For a start, "If Einstein is correct" implies that the speaker thinks he probably is. "If Einstein were correct" suggests a greater degree of scepticism.

Comment: What do you think of number 2? Is it a grammatically correct expression?

Comment: 1 talks about the future ('will be...') and leaves open the question of whether it was possible in the past. 2 and 3 close off that question. @KateBunting is correct about the difference between 2 and 3. All are grammatically correct. I'd use 2 myself.

Comment: Thank  you for your explanation, but i am still not sure, so let me ask you this way. If Einstein is correct, it would be impossible for humans to travel at the speed of light.-If this sentence is correct, do you mean that it might have been possible, but that it is impossible now? I understand number one and three. but I totally don't understand what number 2 means. Please help me if you don't mind.

Comment: For most purposes, #1 and #2 would be understood as having *exactly* the same meaning. The potential fine distinction is that #1 more strongly implies that humans ***will*** try to travel at lightspeed (but they'll won't succeed, because it is/will be impossible). Where #2 implies they might not even ***try*** (but ***if they did***, they ***would*** fail). It's a confusing context though, because the ***reason*** they won't succeed is something "built in" to our current theories, not something where it's meaningful to ***give it a go*** and see what happens (we ***know*** it can't be done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stating facts that are true use zero conditional statements:

> If Einstein was correct, it is impossible for humans to travel at the speed of light.

If Einstein is right, only one thing can happen and it is the fact that "It is impossible for humans to travel at the speed of light."

And that is if you are not planning to explain how modern science might be able to prove that wrong.

Check out [this image](https://www.grammar.cl/rules/conditionals-summary-chart.gif) from [grammar.cl](https://www.grammar.cl) for additional help.